# Is there a way to create 4 columns in an embed?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to design a moderation commands list akin to [this](https://www.remote.tools/remote-work/discord-commands#bot), but when embedding a similar test message, my fourth column starts at a new line.

Is there any way to create a fourth column all in one line or are 3 columns the limit?

I've attached my code, which in theory should display 4 columns. In practice, it doesn't.

```
@client.command()
async def table(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Table", color=color)
    embed.add_field(name="Column One", value="Description", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Column Two", value="Description", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Column Three", value="Description", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Column Four", value="Description", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I haven't seen anyone else do four columns before, so it might not even be possible.

*Note: I would like to post an image of what my current code displays, however I don't have 10 reputation points (which is the minimum required amount).*

Edit: Apparently you cannot have more than 3 columns on desktop Discord, and more than 1 column on mobile.

Comment: You can have up to 25 fields in an embed. Is there an error or does it just not show the 4th?

Comment: You **cannot** have more than 3 "columns" in an embed.

Comment: @mrbean I have had embeds before where I have had 4 fields

Comment: It depends of the width of each field.

Comment: I think on discord on desktop 3 is the max. Keep in mind that on discord mobile, you can only display one column, as far as i know.